# Flutter maximum call stack size exceeded flutter

Tags: android, flutter, retrofit

```
  Future<void> login(String Email, String AppPassword)
  async {

    try {
      const String BASE_URL="http://app.xxxxx.in/api/User/";

      Dio dio = Dio();
      Apis apis = Apis(dio,baseUrl: BASE_URL);

     final response = await apis.login(Email,AppPassword);

      if(response.Success == "true")
      {

        Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()));

      }
      // Handle successful login, e.g., navigate to another screen
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle login error, e.g., show error message to the user
      print('Login failed: $e');


    }

  }
```

I am trying to hit this login rest api but i am always getting same response that is
maximum call stack size exceeded flutter

please help me  out

```
factory Apis(Dio dio, {String? baseUrl}){
    Dio dio = Dio();
  
    return Apis(dio, baseUrl: BASE_URL);

  }

  @POST("/login")
  @FormUrlEncoded()
  Future<LoginResponse> login(@Field("Email") email,@Field("AppPassword") password);
```

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68152653/8144311

Answer (score -1):

However, if this function is called in a context where context is not defined, it could lead to a runtime error. Ensure that context is available within the scope of this function, typically by passing it as a parameter to the function or using it in a widget context where BuildContext is available.

If you're encountering a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error elsewhere in your code, you'll need to look at the code where the error is occurring for the root cause. It's possible that the error is not directly related to this function but rather to another part of your code that is causing excessive recursion. If you have additional code or context where the error is occurring, feel free to provide it, and I can offer further assistance.